# TypeScript define new type based on existing type

Tags: typescript

I am new to ts.

there are two exising type:

```
type A {
    prop1: string
    prop2: B
}

type B {
    prop3: string
    prop4: boolean
}
```

now I want to create a new type as flatted version of A+B

```
{
    prop1: string
    prop3: string
    prop4: boolean
}
```

how to do this in typescript? by referencing existing types.

Comment: So only `prop2` is flattened? Any rules about which properties should be "flattened" and which should not?

Comment: I guess because it's the only one nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this type:

```
   type A  = {
        prop1: string
        prop2: B
    }
    
   type B = {
        prop3: string
        prop4: boolean
    }
    
    type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;
    type Flatten<T, K extends keyof T> = UnionToIntersection<T[K]> & Omit<T, K>;
    
    type Both = Flatten<A,'prop2'>
    
    const result: Both = {prop1: 'one', prop3: 'two', prop4: false}
```

Edit: this is simpler:

```
type Flatten<T, K extends keyof T> =  Omit<T, K> & T[K];
type Both = Flatten<A,'prop2'>
```

Comment: never expected this complex, but at least it's possible, thanks.

Comment: I am curious about why you use `UnionToIntersection`. In this simple case, even just `type Flatten<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & T[K];` seems to work fine.

Comment: What for a good idea @qrsngky thx